# Jquery on click function fired twice

Tags: jquery, click

Help is more than needed.
I just dont know where to dig!
**Suddenly** click event started to fire twice(worked well before). I cannot identify the source of this problem.

Can anyone help?

I'm working on photographer website built on wordpress.
Here is testing website - http://kick-starter.co.il/pregnancy?lang=en&pag=1

This is javascript http://kick-starter.co.il/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/javascript.js
This it my buttons -

```
    $('#right').click(function(){ //click right to change page
    if ( page < pages ){
        page++;
        change_pics( page, album );
        sethash( page, '' );
    }
})

$('#left').click(function(){ //click left to change page
    if ( page > 1 ){
        page--;
        change_pics( page, album );
        sethash( page, '' );
    }
})
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: tried different versions of jquery.

Comment: You have a lot `;` missing in that code.

Comment: ) that's never made any problem. but ill work on it.

Comment: where is page coming from?  Just guessing, but it seems like page could be less than pages and greater than 1

Comment: from address(url) = pag=1

Comment: clicking on social (tweeter, google, vk) do click twice as well.

Comment: I think i found the problem. I used `wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/javascript.js', array( 'jquery' ));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/javascript.js', array( 'jquery' ));` twice and it added javascript.js twice to the code. I removed one instance and it back working. But I dont understand why it worked before. (

Comment: this code in function.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try using preventDefault() and stopPropagation() to prevent multiple event occurrence.

```
$('#right').click(function(e){ //click right to change page
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( page < pages ){
        page++;
        change_pics( page, album );
        sethash( page, '' );
    }
})

$('#left').click(function(e){ //click left to change page
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( page > 1 ){
        page--;
        change_pics( page, album );
        sethash( page, '' );
    }
})
```